# How to delete word from list in python GUI tkinter

Tags: python, list, tkinter

Trying to get a random team generated then eliminate it from the choice list, would like to add a display of "No teams left". But need some help:

```py
from tkinter import *
import random


def teams():
    words_list = [
        'Atlanta Hawks',
        'Boston Celtics',
        'Brooklyn Nets',
        'Charlotte Hornets',
        'Chicago Bulls',
        'Cleveland Cavaliers',
        'Dallas Mavericks',
        'Denver Nuggets',
        'Detroit Pistons',
        'Golden State Warriors',
        'Houston Rockets',
        'Indiana Pacers',
        'Los Angeles Clippers',
        'Los Angeles Lakers',
        'Memphis Grizzlies',
        'Miami Heat',
        'Milwaukee Bucks',
        'Minnesota Timberwolves',
        'New Orleans Pelicans',
        'New York Knicks',
        'Oklahoma City Thunder',
        'Orlando Magic',
        'Philadelphia 76ers',
        'Phoenix Suns',
        'Portland Trail Blazers',
        'Sacramento Kings',
        'San Antonio Spurs',
        'Toronto Raptors',
        'Utah Jazz',
        'Washington Wizards'
    ]

    while words_list:
        team = words_list.pop(random.randrange(len(words_list)))
        label.config(text=team)


window = Tk()
icon = PhotoImage(file='IMG_0612.png')
window.iconphoto(True, icon)
button = Button(window, text='Click me!!!')
button.config(command=teams)  # performs call back of function
button.config(font=('Ink Free', 20, 'bold'))
button.config(bg='#ff6200')
button.config(fg='#fffb1f')
button.config(activebackground='#FF0000')
button.config(activeforeground='#fffb1f')
image = PhotoImage(file='IMG_0612.png')
button.config(image=image)
button.config(compound='bottom')
label = Label(window)
label.config(font=('Monospace', 50))
label.pack()
button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

I was excepting a crash once all words were deleted, but the list just repeats with the button and acts like the remove code is not even there.

Comment: Each time `teams()` is called, the list is recreated with its original contents, because `words_list` is a local variable.

Comment: Gotcha , so what would be the best way of going about that ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you are iterating every time (on each click) over the complete list (until the while-loop ends), because the whole `teams()` function is executed on each click. Second, you're creating on each call to the `teams()` function the same list over and over again. That is, because the `words_list` is created as a local variable inside the function.

To overcome your situation, you can

1. Make the list inside the function nonlocal/global
2. Remove the while-loop inside the `teams()` function

The while-loop is not necessary, also because you're using the same list (same object!) for each function call and `randrange()` don't need any iteration.

So with minimal changes, your code could look like this:

```py
from tkinter import *
import random


WORDS_LIST = [
    'Atlanta Hawks',
    'Boston Celtics',
    'Brooklyn Nets',
    'Charlotte Hornets',
    'Chicago Bulls',
    'Cleveland Cavaliers',
    'Dallas Mavericks',
    'Denver Nuggets',
    'Detroit Pistons',
    'Golden State Warriors',
    'Houston Rockets',
    'Indiana Pacers',
    'Los Angeles Clippers',
    'Los Angeles Lakers',
    'Memphis Grizzlies',
    'Miami Heat',
    'Milwaukee Bucks',
    'Minnesota Timberwolves',
    'New Orleans Pelicans',
    'New York Knicks',
    'Oklahoma City Thunder',
    'Orlando Magic',
    'Philadelphia 76ers',
    'Phoenix Suns',
    'Portland Trail Blazers',
    'Sacramento Kings',
    'San Antonio Spurs',
    'Toronto Raptors',
    'Utah Jazz',
    'Washington Wizards'
]


def teams():
    global WORDS_LIST
    team = WORDS_LIST.pop(random.randrange(len(WORDS_LIST)))
    label.config(text=team)


window = Tk()
icon = PhotoImage(file='IMG_0612.png')
window.iconphoto(True, icon)
button = Button(window, text='Click me!!!')
button.config(command=teams)  # performs call back of function
button.config(font=('Ink Free', 20, 'bold'))
button.config(bg='#ff6200')
button.config(fg='#fffb1f')
button.config(activebackground='#FF0000')
button.config(activeforeground='#fffb1f')
image = PhotoImage(file='IMG_0612.png')
button.config(image=image)
button.config(compound='bottom')
label = Label(window)
label.config(font=('Monospace', 50))
label.pack()
button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

And then, you will get your expected error if the list is empty (`ValueError: empty range for randrange()`), which you can handle, e.g. in a try/except block like this or whatever you want instead:

```py
def teams():
    global WORDS_LIST
    try:
        team = WORDS_LIST.pop(random.randrange(len(WORDS_LIST)))
    except ValueError:
        team = "No team left"
    label.config(text=team)
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-global_stmt) is the documentation for the global statement.

Note: Instead of using `randrange(len_of_your_list)`, you can also use `choice(your_list)`. It is also mentioned in the [randrange](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) documentation.

Comment: Thank you , is there any documentation on say if I added a “Add to team 1” button that will make it call the random team selected to a different label?

Comment: I don't know if I fully understood your request, but there are plenty of resources available for tkinter, the Tcl/Tk interface for Python. This may be a good introduction with links to further resources: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html - If you have again a specific question, you can ask another question, but you should first try yourself, so that we can see where you're stuck (like you did for this question). Also please don't forget to [upvote/accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) this answer if you find it useful.